# Getting exception while performing field faceting

Tags: faceted-search

While doing filed faceting  I am getting the below error.

Exception during facet counts:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field manfar_name
 at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getField(IndexSchema.java:1077)
 at org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.getTermCounts(SimpleFacets.java:226)
 at org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.getFacetFieldCounts(SimpleFacets.java:283)
 at org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.getFacetCounts(SimpleFacets.java:166)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent.process(FacetComponent.java:72)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:195)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
 at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1316)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:5
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

In the schema.xml I mentioned manfar_name  as shown below.

In the solrConfig.xml I configured as shown below.

sal_amt:[* TO 200]
                 sal_amt:[201 TO 300]
                 sal_amt:[301 TO 400]
                 sal_amt:[401 TO 500]
                 sal_amt:[501 TO 600]
                 sal_amt:[601 TO 700]
                 sal_amt:[701 TO 800]
                 sal_amt:[801 TO 900]
                 sal_amt:[901 TO 1000]
                 sal_amt:[1001 TO 2000]
                 manfar_name

The data-import configuration  is given below.

Where my configuration is going wrong?
Please help me to resolve this.

Regards,
Siva Prasad Janapati

Answer (score 0):

this question is quite old so you might have already moved on. 
But it looks like you have an undefined field manfar_name, check your schema.xml file to see if this field is in there.